# Download videos in series one after the other in Node JS using async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I want to download videos one after the other in a series.

That is the first one should be completely downloaded before the second one starts & the second one should be completely downloaded before the third one starts & so on.

I have the following directory structure -

```
video-downloader
├── index.js
├── videos.js
├── package.json
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "video-downloader",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "download": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index"
  }
}
```

## video.js

```
const videos = [
  {
    url: 'https://video.com/lesson1.mp4',
    name: 'Lesson 1',
  },
  {
    url: 'https://video.com/lesson2.mp4',
    name: 'Lesson 2',
  },
  .
  .
  .
  {
    url: 'https://video.com/lesson2.mp4',
    name: 'Lesson 100',
  }
]
```

## index.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const download = require('download')

const videos = require('./videos')

const OUTPUT_DIR = 'Downloads'

fs.mkdir(OUTPUT_DIR, () => {
   main()
})

const main = () => {
    videos.map((video, i) => {
        console.log(`Downloaded file ${i + 1} of ${videos.length} (${video.name})`)
        download(video.url).pipe(
            fs.createWriteStream(`${OUTPUT_DIR}/${video.name}.mp4`),
        )
    })
}
```

This downloads videos chunk by chunk parallelly. All the videos are downloaded at once but none of them gets completed before the other one starts.

How do I download it serially?

I know I should use something like http://caolan.github.io/async/ but it needs a function signature & I have `videos` as an array so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `await` keyword on standard for loops, and things will process in order, and wait on each download before proceeding.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const download = require('download')
const videos = require('./videos')
const util = require('util')

const mkdirAsync = util.promisify(fs.mkdir)

const OUTPUT_DIR = 'Downloads'

const main = async () => {
  await mkdirAsync(OUTPUT_DIR)

  for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    const video = videos[i]
    const data = await download(video.url)
    fs.writeFileSync(`${OUTPUT_DIR}/${video.name}.mp4`, data)
    console.log(`Downloaded file ${i + 1} of ${videos.length} (${video.name})`)
  }
}

main()
```

Comment: np. i just saw your post edit. you might want to look at promisifying your mkdir function (and any other callback-based function) so that you can prevent spaghetti code. i'll edit my post as such

Comment: what difference does that make? i mean its working perfectly fine now.

Comment: Functionally it's no different. I probably was overstepping by suggesting it, sorry. But seeing as I've already suggested it... You're employing two different asynchronous methodologies in one piece of code - a callback, and async/await. If you stick to one, it's less mental load to reason about. The example of promisifying fs.mkdir on its own was a bit contrived - but once you add in more asynchronous actions it will be much easier to reason about if it's only async/await or only callbacks.

Comment: oh no, I was just curious. no need to be sorry. I got it. I also tend to use either one of both & I like async/await more without the try-catch & I tend to write less LOCs so I'll keep mine until it gives me trouble. Then I'll probably try urs. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.reduce` with promises to resolve sequentially, as follows:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const sh = require('shelljs')
const download = require('download')

const videos = require('./videos')

const OUTPUT_DIR = 'Downloads'

sh.mkdir('-p', OUTPUT_DIR)

videos = videos.reduce((acc, item) => {

  return acc.then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      // Here you are using it as a Duplex Stream, not a promise,
      // therefore, you must check when the stream emits the 'end' event
      // so you can proceed further
      let stream = download(video.url)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${OUTPUT_DIR}/${video.name}.mp4`));

      stream.on('end', () => {
        console.log(`stream done ${item}`);
        resolve(item);
      })

    })

  });

}, Promise.resolve());

// 'videos' is now a promise
videos.then((lastPromise) => {

  // using reduce will return the last evaluated item(promise)
  // but reaching the last one means the promises before that have been resolved

  console.log('all files were downloaded');


})
```

Comment: i didn't try this as first one worked for me but have an upvote & thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 1):

Try async await for this. First download and then write in Sync.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sh = require('shelljs');
const download = require('download');

const videos = require('./videos');

const OUTPUT_DIR = 'Downloads';

sh.mkdir('-p', OUTPUT_DIR);

videos.forEach(async (video, i) => {
  console.log(`Downloading ${video.name}. Fil${i + 1}/${videos.length} - `);
  const data = await download(video.url);
  fs.writeFileSync(`${OUTPUT_DIR}/${video.name}.mp4`, data);
});
```

Comment: thank you this works but it downloads in random order. I wish it did it in specified order :)

Comment: This does not work, you will get an array of 100 promise objects, and the download still is in parelel

Comment: map is not needed forEach will work, we don't need array of promises. it will download one content in each iteration of loop. check order of videos array.

Comment: indeed this works but downloads in random order. even with forEach. the 1st solution using for loop works perfectly :)